# git diff -b --color is ignoring entire files that have more than space changes

Tags: git, command-line-interface

**Note:** I think I already answered this, scroll down.

I am using Git version 2.25.1

I'm trying to figure out why, my alias `alias gd="git diff -b --color"` when I run `gd` it's missing entire files.

Example:

Running `gd` is missing the file `ansible/client_plays/ssl.yml`  altogether, then when I run `git diff` it shows it

```
--- a/ansible/client_plays/ssl.yml
+++ b/ansible/client_plays/ssl.yml
@@ -79,4 +79,4 @@ all:
         10.0.1.211:
     nomad-jobs:
-        10.0.1.211:
\ No newline at end of file
+        10.0.1.211:
```

Is there some reason the `-b` would be ignoring those changes? (It's a full omission of IP address, that's major, not just space). Is there some reason `--color` may be ignoring those changes?

### Edit

Gosh, I think I'm misreading this also.  I see it says no new line at the end of the file.  I realize that's my clue.  But I was thinking it was saying the IP was omitted, but looks like it is saying it was put back.

Can I trust this alias in the future?  I just lost my trust in it for a minute there, but looks like I'm good actually.

I'll gather the other example file I had, let's check that one too...

```
+++ b/ansible/playbook.yml
@@ -119,4 +119,4 @@
 - hosts: kibana-dashboard
   tasks:
 - import_role:
-      name: kibana-dashboard
\ No newline at end of file
+      name: kibana-dashboard
```

OK, I think I've just had a long day already.  Can someone comment that either I'm going insane, this looks good and my alias is working as expected? I think it is now, just asking.

Comment: Yes, the two files are the same except for a final newline. `git diff` can only *display* that by claiming that the whole line has changed, then annotating one of the two entries with the `\ No newline...` thing. Since `-b` means "ignore whitespace" and "dropped or added a newline at the end" is a "whitespace" change, `-b` makes that change vanish from the diff, which makes the lines vanish too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a confusing diff, but it is actually only a whitespace change.  The preimage (the old code) contains an identical line to the image (the new code), but without the trailing newline.

This syntax is practically required because you have to an addition and a deletion in the diff so you can place the `\ No newline at end of file` marker after the proper line.  For example, if that marker were after the `+` line, then it would mean that the newline was deleted, not added.